# Be mindful of using vs be mindful of

Tags: grammar

I am really confused with these sentences. I don't know the technical explanation for these. I am studying English and I do not understand what's wrong with the sentences.

1. You just have to be *mindful of using* verbs in your sentences.
2. However, please be *mindful of* articles and word choices.

I was told that *when* should be used for the first sentences. Both sentences are grammatically correct, however, the second sentence is okay and parallel. Also, both are non-standard. Is this correct? Are there any other explanations for this? Also, what are the alternatives for *mindful*? Thank you for your help!

Comment: After writing the two sentences, you wrote that you were told "when" should be used for the first sentence. Where exactly were you told to use it?

Comment: @vickyace "be mindful when using"?

Comment: @vickyace They said that "You just have to be mindful WHEN using verbs in your sentences" is correct.

Answer (score 3):

There's one significant point that I don't think was picked up in the other answers.

Be mindful *of* doing something indicates that you should take care to ensure that you *do* something good, or to be aware of the possibility that you *might* do something unintended. In other words, what you're mindful *of* is the **outcome**. Examples:

- *Be mindful of using verbs in your sentences* tells you that you should be careful to make sure you include verbs in your sentences.
- *Be mindful of upsetting people when you talk about politics in public* tells you that you should consider the possibility of upsetting someone if you talk about politics, and be careful not to.

On the other hand, being mindful *when* speaks about the **action you're performing** rather than its outcome.
- *Be mindful when using verbs in your sentences* assumes that you're using verbs in your sentences, and tells you to be careful when doing so. It doesn't specify of what you should be careful.
- *Be mindful when talking about politics in public* assumes that you will be talking about politics in public, again without specifying why you should be careful.

I am straying into opinion in adding this one last point: I personally think that writing of being mindful *when* without adding what to be mindful *of* is almost always poor English, as it doesn't indicate how to be mindful. Except in a very general sense of "being intentionally aware of yourself", mindfulness really requires an "of" to be meaningful.

Comment: Sometimes it’s obvious though and an “*of*” isn’t required. “You can go,  but be careful when crossing the street.”

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this does seem correct to me. "When" could be used in place of "of" in both sentences, with an inserted "using" in the second, i.e., "be mindful when using..." In this sense mindful means be careful, and an editor might shorten and clarify both by writing instead "Be careful when using verbs, articles, and word choices in your sentences." Or "Use care when writing."

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered a difference between 'be mindful to do s.th.' and 'be mindful of doing s.th.', where the first indicates what you should do, whereas the second points out what to avoid.
Examples: 'Be mindful to turn the lights off' (i.e. make sure you turn the lights off) and 'Be mindful of leaving the lights on' (i.e. don't leave them on).